# How to show multiple data source data in single recycle view or adapter using LazyLoading?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, adapter

[image]

The above image is a simple design that I want to develop.
I have four type of different data with different view type like the below image enter image description here. but that is not a problem. problem is the data will come from different API with lazy loading like when user scroll the list from recycle view it will grab the data from the server. My question is how to combine them in a single adapter because I need to use lazy loading .so I can't load whole data at a time so I need to call the different type of API like goal-list API, appraisal API, post API etc. When user scroll. anyone can give me an idea with example. How can I handle that? Also when user will scroll it will call another api likeCount and comment count also. Currently, In my, I am calling single API and show that in the single recycle view. Currently, I am using android architecture component LiveData

**Fragment :**

```
public class NewsFeedFragment extends FcaFragment {

    private View view;
    private RecyclerView postRecyclerView;
    private PostsAdapter postsAdapter;
    private List<Post> posts;
    private TimelineViewModel timelineViewModel;
    private ImageView addPostView;
    private View addPostPanel;
    private long lastApiCallTime;
    private SwipyRefreshLayout swipeRefresh;
    private long lastScroolItemInPost= 0;

    public NewsFeedFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(lastScroolItemInPost  < 1) {
            initViewModel(1 , 0 , true);
            lastScroolItemInPost = 1;
        }else {
            initViewModel(((int) lastScroolItemInPost + 5), lastScroolItemInPost , true);
            lastScroolItemInPost += 5;
        }


        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ownerActivity);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feed, container, false);
        postRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.postRecyclerView);
        postRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView postRecyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(postRecyclerView, dx, dy);


                int lastVisiableItemInPostList   = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();


                if(lastScroolItemInPost < lastVisiableItemInPostList)
                {
                        if(lastScroolItemInPost == 1)
                        {
                        initViewModel((int) (lastScroolItemInPost + 2), ( lastScroolItemInPost - 2 )  , false);
                        lastScroolItemInPost += 2;
                        }else{
                            initViewModel((int) (lastScroolItemInPost + 2), ( lastScroolItemInPost - 2 ) , false );
                            lastScroolItemInPost += 2;
                        }


                }

               }

        });

        posts = new ArrayList<>();

        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        postsAdapter = new PostsAdapter(ownerActivity,posts,timelineViewModel);
        postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
        swipeRefresh = (SwipyRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipyRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh(SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection direction) {
                if(direction == SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection.TOP){
                    timelineViewModel.fetchPosts2();
                }

                if(direction == SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection.BOTTOM){
                    timelineViewModel.fetchPosts();
                }
            }
        });




        return view;
    }




    private void initViewModel(int lastVisiableItemInPostList , long lastScroolItemInPost , boolean isFirstTimeOpenFeedFragment) {
        TimelineViewModel.Factory factory = new TimelineViewModel.Factory(UserPreferences.getToken(ownerActivity), TaskUtils.getMySelfContact(ownerActivity));
        timelineViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,factory).get(TimelineViewModel.class);
        timelineViewModel.getPostList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Post> posts) {

                postsAdapter.setPostList(posts);
                swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);

            }
        });
        timelineViewModel.getPostDeleted().observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean aBoolean) {
                if(aBoolean){
                    postsAdapter.setPostList(Post.getAll());
                }
            }
        });
        timelineViewModel.init( lastVisiableItemInPostList ,  lastScroolItemInPost ,isFirstTimeOpenFeedFragment);
    }

}
```

**ViewModel :**

```
public class TimelineViewModel extends FCViewModel implements PostDetailsDownloadManager.PostDetailDownloadedListener,OnContactReceivedListner{





    public TimelineViewModel(String token,Contact user){
        super(token);
        this.user = user;

        post = new MutableLiveData<>();
        postDeleted = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public void init(int lastVisiableItemInPostList , long lastScroolItemInPost , boolean isFirstTimeOpenFeedFragment){
        repository = 
        //postDetailsDownloadManager = ServiceLocator.getServiceLocator().postDetailsDownloadManager;

        likePostDownloadManager = ServiceLocator.getServiceLocator().likePostDownloadManager;
        likePostDownloadManager.setPostDetailDownloadedListener(new DataDownloadManager.DataDownloadedListener<LikePostTouple>() {
            @Override
            public void onDataDownloaded(List<LikePostTouple> dataTouple) {
                TimelineViewModel.this.post.setValue(Post.getAll());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSingleDataDownloaded(LikePostTouple dataTouple) {

            }
        });

        postDetailDownloadManager = ServiceLocator.getServiceLocator().postDetailDownloadManager;
        postDetailDownloadManager.setPostDetailDownloadedListener(new DataDownloadManager.DataDownloadedListener<PostTouple>() {
            @Override
            public void onDataDownloaded(List<PostTouple> dataTouple) {
                TimelineViewModel.this.post.setValue(Post.getAll());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSingleDataDownloaded(PostTouple dataTouple) {

            }
        });
        post.setValue(Post.getAll());
        if(isFirstTimeOpenFeedFragment)
        {
            fetchPosts2();
        }

        try {
            if(Post.getAll().size() > 0)
            {
                List<Post> tempPosts = Post.getAll();
                List<Post> passList = tempPosts.subList( (int) lastScroolItemInPost ,lastVisiableItemInPostList);
                fetchLikesOfPosts(passList);
            }else{
                fetchLikesOfPosts(Post.getAll());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Log.d("Testing Injecting", repository.toString());
    }

    public LiveData<List<Post>> getPostList() {
        return post;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> getPostDeleted() {
        return postDeleted;
    }

    boolean isContactFetched = false;

    public void fetchPosts(){
        if(Contact.getAll().size() < 1){
            fetchContacts();
            return;
        }
        Map<String,Object> requestData = new HashMap<>();
        requestData.put("type",1);
        requestData.put("cpid",Post.getLastPid());
        isDataLoading = true;
        repository.getData(new Repository.DataFetchedListener<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onDataFetched(List<Post> posts) {
                isDataLoading = false;
                Log.d("fetched posts",""+posts.size());
                post.setValue(Post.getAll());
                fetchPostDetails(posts);
                if(posts.size() > 0){
                    fetchLikesOfPosts(posts);
                }
            }
        },requestData);
    }


    private boolean isDataLoading = false;
    public void fetchPosts2(){
        if(Contact.getAll().size() < 1){
            fetchContacts();
            return;
        }
        Map<String,Object> requestData = new HashMap<>();
        requestData.put("type",2);
        requestData.put("cpid", Post.getFirstPid()); // cpid means cursor pid
        isDataLoading = true;
        repository.getData(new Repository.DataFetchedListener<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onDataFetched(List<Post> posts) {
                isDataLoading = false;
                Log.d("fetched posts",""+posts.size());
                post.setValue(Post.getAll());
                fetchPostDetails(posts);
                if(posts.size() > 0){
                    fetchLikesOfPosts(posts);
                }
            }
        },requestData);
    }

    public boolean isDataLoading() {
        return isDataLoading;
    }



    private void fetchContacts() {
        contactRepository.getData(new Repository.DataFetchedListener<List<Contact>>() {
            @Override
            public void onDataFetched(List<Contact> data) {
                if(data.size()>0 && !isContactFetched) {
                    fetchPosts2();
                    isContactFetched = true;
                }
            }
        },null);
    }



    @NonNull
    private PostTouple getPostToubleFromPost(Post post) throws JSONException {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        String json =   gson.toJson(post);
        JSONObject postJson = new JSONObject(json);
        return new PostTouple(postJson,post.getPid());
    }

    @NonNull
    private LikePostTouple getLkePostToupleFromPost(Post post) throws JSONException {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        String json =   gson.toJson(post);
        JSONObject postJson = new JSONObject(json);
        return new LikePostTouple(postJson,post.getPid());
    }

    public void giveLike(String token, final long pid){
        Map<String,Object> requestData = new HashMap<>();
        requestData.put("token",token);
        requestData.put("pid",Long.toString(pid));

        likeRepository.postData(new Repository.DataFetchedListener<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onDataFetched(Post data) {
                Log.d("Like post", data.toString());
                Post post = getPostById(pid);
                post.setLikes(data.getLikes());
                post.setComments(data.getComments());
                TimelineViewModel.this.post.setValue(TimelineViewModel.this.post.getValue());
                fetchLikesOfLikedPost(data);
            }
        },requestData);
    }

    private void fetchLikesOfLikedPost(Post data) {
        try {
            likePostDownloadManager.addItemInQueue(getLkePostToupleFromPost(data));
            likePostDownloadManager.startDownload();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Post getPostById(long pid){
        List<Post> posts = post.getValue();
        for(Post post : posts){
            if(post.getPid()==pid){
                return post;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Contact getSenderContactFromComment(Post post) {
        if(post.getPqrc().equals(user.getUserId())){
            return user;
        }
        Contact contact = Contact.getByUserId(post.getPqrc());

        return contact;
    }

    public String getDescriptionForType5(Post post,String message){

        try {
            PostDetail postDetail = PostDetail.getByPostId(post.getPid());
            if(postDetail!=null) {
                String qrc = JSonUtils.qrcFromCntOfPostDetails(postDetail.getContent());
                int sid = JSonUtils.skillidFromCntOfPostDetails(postDetail.getContent());
                if (qrc == null || sid == 0) {
                    return "";
                }
                SkillDb skill = SkillDb.getBySId(Integer.toString(sid));

                Contact contact = getPosterContact(post.getPqrc());

                return contact.getName() + " " + message + " " + skill.getSkillName() + ".";
            }

            return "";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public String getDescriptionForPost(Post post, String message){
        if(post.getCtype()==1){
            return post.getDescr();
        }

        if(post.getCtype() == 2){
            String postDetail = getContent(post);
            if (postDetail != null) return Html.fromHtml("<a href=\""+ postDetail +"\">"+postDetail+"</a>").toString();
        }

        if(post.getCtype()==5){
            return getDescriptionForType5(post, message);
        }

        return "";

    }

    @Nullable
    public String getContent(Post post) {
        PostDetail postDetail = PostDetail.getByPostId(post.getPid());
        if(postDetail!=null){
            return postDetail.getContent();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public Contact getPosterContact(String qrc){
        try {
            String userqrc = user.getUserId();
            if (userqrc.equals(qrc)) {
                return user;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            return Contact.getByUserId(qrc);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void fetchUrlPreview(String url, final UrlMetaDataFetchListener metaDataFetchListener){
        String modifiedUrl = !url.contains("http://")&&!url.contains("https://")? "http://"+url : url;
        TextCrawler textCrawler = new TextCrawler();


        LinkPreviewCallback linkPreviewCallback = new LinkPreviewCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPre() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPos(SourceContent sourceContent, boolean b) {
                String imageUrl = sourceContent.getImages().isEmpty()? "" : sourceContent.getImages().get(0);
                metaDataFetchListener.onMetaDataFetched(sourceContent.getTitle(),sourceContent.getDescription(), imageUrl);
            }
        };

        textCrawler.makePreview(linkPreviewCallback, modifiedUrl,1);
    }


    public interface UrlMetaDataFetchListener{
        void onMetaDataFetched(String title, String description, String imageUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostDownloaded(PostTouple postTouple) {
        this.post.setValue(Post.getAll());
    }

    @Override
    public void onContactsReceived() {
        fetchPosts();
    }


    public void deletePost(long pid) {
        Map<String, Object> requestData = new HashMap<>();
        requestData.put("token",token);
        requestData.put("pid",pid);
        repository.postData(new Repository.DataFetchedListener<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onDataFetched(Post data) {
                postDeleted.setValue(data!=null);
            }
        },requestData);
    }

    public boolean isMyPost(Post post){
        return user.getUserId().equals(post.getPqrc());
    }

    public static class Factory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

         private String token;
         private Contact user;

        public Factory(String token,Contact user) {
            this.token = token;
            this.user = user;
        }

        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {

            return (T) new TimelineViewModel(token,user);
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter :**

public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Context context;
private List<Post> postList;
private int[] badges = {R.drawable.badge1, R.drawable.badge2, R.drawable.badge3};
private List<Integer> randomNumbers = Utils.getRandomNumberList(2,true);
private ArrayDeque<Integer> randomQueue = new ArrayDeque<>(randomNumbers);
private static Map<Long,URLPreview> urlPreviewMap = new HashMap<>();
private TimelineViewModel timelineViewModel;

public PostsAdapter(Context context, List<Post> postList, TimelineViewModel timelineViewModel){
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.postList = postList;
    this.timelineViewModel = timelineViewModel;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_item_layout, null);
    PostViewHolder postViewHolder = new PostViewHolder(view);
    postViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    return postViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Post post = postList.get(position);
    final PostViewHolder postViewHolder = (PostViewHolder) holder;
    final String postDetail = timelineViewModel.getDescriptionForPost(post,context.getResources().getString(R.string.postType5message));


    setPostDescription(post, postViewHolder, postDetail);
    handlePreviewVisibility(post, postViewHolder);


    postViewHolder.setLikes(""+post.getLikes()+" Likes");
    postViewHolder.setCommentCount("" + post.getComments() + " Comments");
    postViewHolder.setSupDescription("Posted By System");

    int randomNumber = getRandomNumber();
    postViewHolder.setBadgeIcon(badges[randomNumber]);

    setPostLikedIndicator(post, postViewHolder);

    postViewHolder.getLikeButtonWrapper().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            giveLikeToPost(post);
            if(post.getIsLiked() == 0) {
                post.setLikes(post.getLikes() + 1);
                postViewHolder.setLikes("" + post.getLikes() + " Likes");
                post.setIsLiked(1);
                setPostLikedIndicator(post, postViewHolder);
            }
        }
    });

    postViewHolder.getCommentPanel().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CommentPostFragment fragment = CommentPostFragment.GetInstance(post.getPid());
            ViewUtils.launchFragmentKeepingInBackStack(context,fragment);
        }
    });

    Contact contact = timelineViewModel.getPosterContact(post.getPqrc());

    if(contact!=null && TaskUtils.isNotEmpty(contact.getImageToken())){
        Utils.setImageToImageView(postViewHolder.getPosterImage(),timelineViewModel.getToken(),contact.getImageToken());
        postViewHolder.getPosterNameTextView().setText(contact.getName());
    }


    postViewHolder.getPostingDate().setText(Utils.getDateFromMilliseconds(post.getdC()));
    if(post.getCtype() != 3)
    {

        postViewHolder.contentImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        postViewHolder.fullScreenIndicatorIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if(post.getCtype() == 3){
        setContentOfType3(post, postViewHolder);
    }




}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    PostViewHolder viewHolder = (PostViewHolder) holder;
    viewHolder.pTitle.setText("");
    viewHolder.pDescription.setText("");
    viewHolder.pImage.setImageDrawable(null);

}

private void handlePreviewVisibility(Post post, PostViewHolder postViewHolder) {
    if(post.getCtype()==2){
        postViewHolder.preview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        postViewHolder.preview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void handleShowingOptionsIcon(Post post, PostViewHolder postViewHolder) {
    if(post.getCtype()!=5 && timelineViewModel.isMyPost(post)){
        postViewHolder.options.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        postViewHolder.options.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}





private void giveLikeToPost(Post post) {
    post.setLikes(post.getLikes()+1);

    post.setIsLiked(1);

    //notifyDataSetChanged();

    timelineViewModel.giveLike(UserPreferences.getToken(context),post.getPid());

}

private void setPostLikedIndicator(Post post, PostViewHolder postViewHolder) {
    if(post.getIsLiked()==1) {
        postViewHolder.getLikeButton().setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_like_red, null));
    }else{
        postViewHolder.getLikeButton().setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_like_filled, null));
    }
}

private void setPostDescription(final Post post, final PostViewHolder postViewHolder, final String postDetail) {
    if(post.getCtype()==2){

        String postDescription = "<p>"+ post.getDescr()+"</p>";
        postViewHolder.description.setText( Html.fromHtml(postDescription +"<a href=\""+ postDetail +"\">"+postDetail+"</a>")  );
        postViewHolder.descriptionContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = !postDetail.contains("http://")&&!postDetail.contains("https://")? "http://"+postDetail : postDetail;
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri));
            }
        });
        URLPreview urlPreview = null;
        if((urlPreview=urlPreviewMap.get(post.getPid()))==null) {
            timelineViewModel.fetchUrlPreview(postDetail, new TimelineViewModel.UrlMetaDataFetchListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMetaDataFetched(String title, String description, String imageUrl) {
                    showURLPreview(title, description, imageUrl, postViewHolder);
                    urlPreviewMap.put(post.getPid(),new URLPreview(title,description,imageUrl));
                }
            });
        }else {
            showURLPreview(urlPreview.getTitle(),urlPreview.getDescription(),urlPreview.getImageUrl(),postViewHolder);
        }

    }else if(post.getCtype() == 3)
    {
      String postDescription = post.getDescr();
      postViewHolder.description.setText(postDescription);
    }
    else {
        postViewHolder.setDescription(postDetail);
    }
}
private void initImageClickListener(final ImageView imageView, final String pictureLink) {
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            List<String> pictureLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
            pictureLinks.add(pictureLink);


            int[] screenLocation = new int[2];
            imageView.getLocationOnScreen(screenLocation);

            ImagePagerFragment imagePagerFragment = ImagePagerFragment.newInstance(pictureLinks, 0, screenLocation, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
            ViewUtils.launchPopUpFragmentUpdated(context, imagePagerFragment);
        }
    });
}


private void showURLPreview(String title, String description, String imageUrl, PostViewHolder postViewHolder) {
```

context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

```
    if(!TaskUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(postViewHolder.pImage);
    }
```

view.findViewById(R.id.description);

```
    postViewHolder.pTitle.setText(title);
    postViewHolder.pDescription.setText(description);


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return postList.size();
}

private int getRandomNumber(){
    if(!randomQueue.isEmpty()){
        return randomQueue.poll();
    }

    randomQueue = new ArrayDeque<>(randomNumbers);
    return randomQueue.poll();
}

public void setPostList(List<Post> postList) {
    this.postList = postList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d("Data rec", postList.size()+"");
}

class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {




    }

    public void setLikes(String likes) {
        this.likes.setText(likes);
    }
    public void setCommentCount(String commentCount)
    {
        this.commentCount.setText(commentCount);
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description.setText(description);
    }

    public void setSupDescription(String subDescription){
        this.supDescription.setText(subDescription);
    }

    public void setBadgeIcon(int resID){
        Utils.setImageViewFromResource(badgeIcon,resID);
    }

    public ImageView getLikeButton() {
        return likeButton;
    }
    public RelativeLayout getLikeButtonWrapper()
    {
        return likeButtonWrapper;
    }

    public ImageView getCommentButton() {
        return commentButton;
    }

    public ImageView getPosterImage() {
        return posterImage;
    }

    public TextView getPosterNameTextView() {
        return posterNameTextView;
    }

    public TextView getPostingDate() {
        return postingDate;
    }

    public RelativeLayout getCommentPanel() {
        return commentPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        timelineViewModel.deletePost(postList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPid());
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library

Comment: I have mentioned need different type data combine

Comment: you can still use `paging` library

Comment: Can you provide any examples?

Comment: of `PagedListAdapter`? see the official documentation

Comment: Ok i will check thanks. But is there any other solution?